# How to check if $(ConfigurationName) contains a string

Tags: c#, visual-studio, post-build-event

I have multi ConfigurationName: Release-2018, Release-2019, Release-2020, Debug-2018, Debug-2019, Debug-2020

How can I check if "$(ConfigurationName)" contains "Release"?

I have tried:

```
if "$(ConfigurationName)".Contains("Release") ....<do something>
```

Currently I used:

```
if "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release-2018" ....<do something>

if "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release-2019" ....<do something>

if "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release-2020" ....<do something>
```

but It seems a bad solution.

Is there any function to help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to define **Conditional compliation symbols** in your Build properties for each **Configuration**.

[image]

Then you can run custom code section based on your symbols by conditional if-else directives.

```
#if YOURCFG1
Console.WriteLine("YourCfg is selected build configuration");
//<do something>
#endif
```